# How can I create a wxMenu with only bitmaps

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I would like to draw a `wxMenu` where the items are drawn as bitmaps with a size of my choosing. I know I can call `SetBitmap` etc on a `wxMenuItem`, but that leaves space on both the left right for the item label etc.

I know how to do this using MFC, where I would subclass `CMenu` and override `DrawItem` and `MeasureItem` so it should at least be possible with the native windows controls.

Is it possible to subclass `wxMenu` to get the behavior I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `OnMeasureItem()` and `OnDrawItem()` in your own `wxMenuItem` subclass, but this will indeed work under MSW only.

You might also want to take a look at the [ownerdraw sample](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/tree/v3.1.4/samples/ownerdrw/ownerdrw.cpp).

Comment: Thanks, that was what I thought

Comment: Working link: https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/samples/ownerdrw/ownerdrw.cpp

Comment: Oops, fixed the link, sorry.